# Basic element extraction?

Tags: python

I need to extract the two values from "transpose_a" and assign them to new variables. 
Instead, this code is assigning both values in transpose_a to a1 and throwing an error after the "print(a1)" command. I understand why- just not how to fix.

```
print(transpose_a)
a1 = list(np.array(transpose_a)[0])
print(a1)
a2 = transpose_a[1]

#transpose_a
[[ 0.5856155   2.12569922]]
#a1
[0.58561549937881319, 2.1256992229105975]
```

Comment: We need more help over here. How does `transpose_a` look like? Is `[[ 0.5856155   2.12569922]]` `transpose_a` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, `transpose_a` is a list of lists, which has 1 element:`[ 0.5856155   2.12569922]`. So if you run `transpose_a[0]`, you access that element. Now if you want to access the first element of this element, you do:

```
a1 = list(np.array(transpose_a)[0])[0]
a2 = list(np.array(transpose_a)[0])[1]
```

Comment: That still gives an error- IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Comment: My edit should do, but I don't quite understand what is `transpose_a`. There's something wrong in what you showed us, because `transpose_a =[[ 0.5856155   2.12569922]]` brings a `SyntaxError`. What's the output of `type(transpose_a)` ?

Comment: <class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'> it now works thanks! I'll mark correct as soon as the website lets me